# add NSTimeInterval to NSDate in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, time, sum, nsdate

I've got a `NSDate` that represents a specific time. The format of that date is hhmmss. I want to add an `NSInterval` value (specified in seconds) to that time value.

Example:

```
NSDate =         123000
NSTimeInterval = 3600

Added together = 133000
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have you seen the [Dates and Times Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000183) manual?

Basically you need to convert your time into an NSDate. To convert a string to a date you use the `NSDateFormatter` class or maybe `NSDateComponents` if you already know the hours, minutes and seconds.

Your `NSTimeInterval` is just a double (i.e., 3600.0).

Then you use the `dateByAddingTimeInterval` method of NSDate to add the number of seconds to the time.

```
NSDate* newDate = [oldDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600.0];
```

You can then use either `NSDateFormatter` or `NSDateComponents` to get the new time back out again.

Comment: addTimeInterval: Deprecated in iOS 4.0. Use dateByAddingTimeInterval: - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @SeungUnHam Indeed. The answer was written when iPhone OS 2.x was current(!), but I've updated it to reflect the current recommendation.

Answer (score 8):

addTimeInterval is now deprecated.  Try using [dateByAddingTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/dateByAddingTimeInterval%3a) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
// This will set the time when your view appears it will also
// set the time if you want to retrieve from it.
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     //Create todays date
     NSDate *duedate = [NSDate date];
     //Add how ever many days you could write 86400*numbe_of_days days 86400/24 for an hour
     //Then simply reassign the variable or use a different one.
     duedate = [duedate dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];  //I add one day
     [datePicker setDate:duedate animated:YES]; //Animate yes will show your pickers moving
     [datePicker setMinimumDate:duedate]; //Set minimum date.
}
```